How to set one specific application on my laptop to be able to bypass router's WireGuard VPN and connect directly to the ISP?
I have a Keenetic router with WireGuard VPN enabled for all devices including my laptop.
My laptop runs Window 10 and connects to the internet through this router via LAN cable.
I want one specific application on my laptop to bypass router's WireGuard VPN and connect directly to the ISP.
Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe some software solutions on Windows and Keenetic?

Your router needs to be able to identify the "special" connection in order to handle it differently. Typically this is done using some combination of:

The source IP.
The source port
The destination IP
The destination port.
The protocol (UDP, TCP)

Assuming your computer initiates the connection it is typically easier to add a rule to the router based on either the destination IP or destination port.
Failing that, if this is a custom application, you can bind a particular port on the outgoing connection (source port).
Lastly if no other options are available, you could alias your network card (assign a second IP to it) then use that IP for the outbound connection (source IP).
Since you haven't provided any details about the service you are trying handle, I have no way to say which of these options is best for you.

@davidgo makes a good point.
IP defines two packet classification standards 802.1p (Layer 2) and DSCP (Layer 3) since 802.1p is part of the trunking/VLAN header (802.1q) that probably won't be useful to you.
However Windows supports DSCP tagging, on a per application basis.
From a bit of googling it looks like Keenetic routers also support DSCP however it wasn't clear in the pages I read (specifically with respect to Keenetic routers) if DSCP is only used for prioritization/scheduling or if you can make routing decisions based on it.
I have done a bit more digging. Routing based on DSCP is possible on linux, but it's a process specifically you need to:

Create a second routing table.
Add a PREROUTING rule to set a fwmark on the packet based on the dscp value.
Add an ip rule to send the data to the alternate routing table if the fwmark is set.

TL;DR - I doubt out of the box firmware on most lower end routers is going to support that, so this approach is probably a no go on that hardware.

Another (less likely I suspect) is a QOS identifier. I've seen this used for tagging packets and being acted on for routing.

What if I can't control application behavior, and it connects to different IPs all the time?

@ehpc: Then you still need to think of a way to identify its connections, based on the list in this answer. If everything about the destination can change, then "The source IP" (i.e. the IP of your laptop) is still in your control – as DavidT already mentioned, you might be able to e.g. assign two LAN IP addresses to your laptop, and then configure your program to bind to one of them as the "local IP address" – or use a tool like "ForceBindIP" if the program doesn't have such an option. If you can't control literally any items in the list... then you can't do it, end of story.
